# How to use HTML/CSS to show images and titles inline?

Tags: html, css, image, inline

I have 2 images that I want to show side by side, with the title above as part of a hyperlink.

```
  <div id="image">

  <a href="file:///L:/file" style="text-decoration:none;"  Title="Project Reports">
  <p>New Reports</p>
  <img src="http://tableau/" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /> 
  </a>       


  <a href="file:///L:/file2" style="text-decoration:none;" >
  <p>Project Reports</p>
  <img src="http://tableau/" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
  </a>
```

If I remove the p tag around the titles, it displays inline, but I need the title to be on top of the image.

CSS:

```
  #image {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you learn how to use HTML and CSS, and write the HTML properly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too specific / localized

Comment: wow so many haters. I took an html class 6 years ago and am doing this in notepad the best I can.  I'm a SQL/c# dev, not the most versed in HTML/CSS. My apologies for seeking help.  fwiw, junkfoodjunkie answered it correct.  If this stays open, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. Proper HTML and CSS.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="image">
 <a href="file:///L:/file" title="Project Reports">New Reports<br>
  <img src="http://tableau/" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /> 
  </a>      


  <a href="file:///L:/file2">Project Reports<br>
  <img src="http://tableau/" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You!  I kept overlooking my a tag, and putting the inline-block in the wrong places. Sorry I do not live up to your standards in HTML, but I do appreciate the help.  I knew that was the answer, but once again, was putting it everywhere except in the a css sheet.

Comment: You also used the `<p>`-tag, which isn't needed - and if it was needed, it should have wrapped the `<a>`, not the other way around. `<a>` is `inline` by default, so to make everything work as intended, all one needs to do is create some sort of `block`-element, and make sure it also displays inline.
You can of course also style the text by adding styling to the `<a>`-tag, or adding a `<span>`-wrapper for the text and style that specifically.

Comment: Could I have got there from google, yes.  Would I have had the proper HTML/CSS?  Probably not, which is why I came here.  There are many ways to do the same thing, and I wanted to ensure I'm doing it correctly.  It's just a really small HTML file.  I have a personal site that passes wc3 validations so I'm not as terrible as you may think lol.

Comment: As of HTML5 the a tag is no longer constained to only contain phrasing content (aka inline tags). It may now also contain flow content (aka block tags).  http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html  Therefore putting the p tag inside of the a tag is just fine.  Just be sure to style the a tag accordingly so that you don't have any layout weirdness.

Comment: (Assuming you are using the HTML5 doctype) :-)

Comment: Yes, I know. That doesn't make it sane or smart.

Answer (score 1):

add `float:left;` in `a`

```css
#image {
  display: inline-block;
  width:1000px;
  clear:both;
}
#image > a{
  float: left;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <a href="file:///L:/file" style="text-decoration:none;"  Title="Project Reports">
  <p>New Reports</p>
  <img src="http://tableau/" style="width:304px;height:228px;" /> 
  </a>       
  <a href="file:///L:/file2" style="text-decoration:none;" >
  <p>Project Reports</p>
  <img src="http://tableau/" style="width:304px;height:228px;"/>
  </a>
```

Comment: This is stacking the images, but I need them to be side by side